# Get All src image selected container

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to get all src image url from selected container , i tried using for loop but not able to get it done.

I tried following code , but i am getting output as Null

```
WebElement img=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='center_column']/div[2]"));
List<WebElement> imgclass= img.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@itemprop='url']"));
for(int i=0;i<imgclass.size();i++){
List<WebElement> srcimg=imgclass.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("img"));
for(int j=0 ;j<imgclass.size();j++){                      System.out.println("Output"+imgclass.get(j).getAttribute("href"));
}
```

But cant figure out why i am getting duplicate URL:

Comment: It would be easier if you just linked the site. That's a lot of HTML to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are trying to get images from `a` tags while images are present in `img` tag

use below Xpath

```
//img[@itemprop='image']
```

Above Xpath will return you elements of all images

You can use the below xpath for the `href`

```
//a[@class='product_img_link' and @href[contains(.,'262')]]
```

Change the value from 262 to 261 if you want other image href

now just `.getAttribute("href")` to retrive complete url. like below:-

```
String a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='product_img_link' and @href[contains(.,'262')]]")).getAttribute("href");
```

Complete Code:-

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.domain.com/categories");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='product_img_link' and @href[contains(.,'261')]]")).getAttribute("href"); 
System.out.println(a);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification , can u re write my code so that i can get where i was getting wrong ??

Comment: Actually i am getting src url , but fact is i want to get href , i tried to use it but i am getting duplicate url coz there is two 'a' tag . How to get it out..

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , i am not getting where to put in , it will more helpful to if u can frame my existing code .

Comment: I had done same , but it is showing me NoSuchElement exception.

Comment: Yes u have missed wait -> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Still getting NoSuchElement Exception

Comment: Thanks Sujit ... do u want me to delete all URL links ... I have seen your edit request.. If you want I can remove those from your side :)

Comment: Yes Please , Thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the site and verified that this code works.

```
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.product_list img"));
for (WebElement image : images)
{
    System.out.println(image.getAttribute("src"));
}
```

The CSS Selector is looking for `IMAGE` tags that are descendants of the `DIV` with a class `product_list`. It then loops through the `List` and writes out the `src` attribute for each `IMAGE`.

Comment: Thanks @Jeffc , its work ....But cant figure out how to come up with this selector "div.product_list img". , ..Much appreciated if you can explain me ..

Comment: The way I typically approach a task like this is to find an element that contains all the product info for a given product... I refer to this as the "container" element. In this case, that's the `DIV` with the class `product_list`. You want the `IMG` tag for each product so you find the descendant `IMG` for your "container" `DIV` which is `"div.product_list img"`. Here's a good [reference for CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors). I would suggest you read some tutorials. CSS selectors are very powerful and are a good tool for any automator.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @JeffC , i want to get href of image , here i am getting src , how to get href of image , as there i see two href in 'a ' ; a bit confused how to get distinct href.

Comment: I think you are confusing a couple different HTML tags. The `IMG` tag has a `src` attribute and the `A` tag has the `href` attribute. The question you asked here was about `src` from `IMG` tags. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img for more info. If you have another question, you should mark an answer here and then start a new question.